# Unable to Configure SSL Certificate install on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk Server

Tags: ssl, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to add the SSL Certificate to the amazon services "Elastic Beanstalk Server". I am trying to add it by using Load Balancer. After configuring it , I am viewing the IIS defualt page. For Furthur Description I am attaching the screen shots .[image]

URL redirects to the IIS Default Page 
https://itpmba-dev.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/
Where my other environment is 
http://itpmba-prod.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/ is working fine . But This is with out SSL certificate

Comment: The question is not very clear. What happens if you turn on port 80 ("Listener Port")?

Comment: Still it redirects to IIS default Page. I am facing some trouble shooting error while adding the SSL Certificate. Do I need to add some config files.

Comment: You are seeing the IIS default page, but can you tell us what you were expecting to see?

Comment: @Dennis I was expected to see website hosted over amazon with https as it was earlier without https

Comment: Does itpmba.com redirect to itpmba-dev or itpmba-prod? A working setup could be as follows: suppose you own "my-example.net", redirect it to "my-example-dev.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com" (without "http://" or "https://") using a CNAME record (through external DNS hosting service). Obtain a certificate for "my-example.net" through the aws certificate manager. Then configure the load balancer for "my-example-dev" to use this certificate and listen on port 443, as you have done above. Then you should be able to visit "https://my-example.net"

Comment: that should be https:// my-example.net (could not edit anymore)